# How do I check if a remote event is fired with a if statement

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a remote event is fired with an if statement so if it is fired then i want to do something. And yes I know you can do remote.OnClient or ServerEvent:Connect(function() end) but that is not what im trying to do

I haven't tried anything yet because I have been looking on how to do it

Comment: Take a quick read through this : https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/events/remote